# Update Select Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO article (article_title, article_credits, article_excerpt, 
article_body, article_img_list, article_img_main,
article_published, article_date, article_modified, article_author) ".

"SELECT '".$db->escape($post['title'])."', '".json_encode($credits)."','".$db->escape($post['excerpt']).
   "','".$db->escape($post['article'])."','".$db->escape($articleImageListName)."
','".$db->escape($articleImageMainName)."
','".$published."',
'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($post['date']))."',
'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', email ". 
                 "FROM users WHERE id = ".$id"";
```

The above query inserts data into my database and selects email from users.

How can I convert this to an UPDATE query?

Comment: Please could you add newlines to the code so it is more easily readable?

Answer (score 2):

Add `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` and take care that there is something that is unique and can't be changed like an `article_ID` that exists in the old *and* in the new article

BTW: I would recommend using prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`.

For `UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE` you have write a lot of overhead assignments in the end.